# AWS CloudFront Error An error occurred (NoSuchDistribution) when calling the CreateInvalidation operation: The specified distribution does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, invalidation, cache-invalidation

User having the Cloud Front Policy

```
{
  "Statement": [  
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation",
        "cloudfront:GetInvalidation",
        "cloudfront:ListInvalidations"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

But getting error as : AWS CloudFront Error An error occurred (NoSuchDistribution) when calling the CreateInvalidation operation: The specified distribution does not exist.